# Elasticsearch, some rows missing from the search results

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

In my index I've got 40 rows with data like this:

```
| -name- | -surname- | -bdate string- |  -creation date-          |
| leva   | agabalyan | 19560901       |  2013-09-21T11:19:13.968Z |
| leva   | agabalyan | 19560901       |  2012-03-14T11:16:47.665Z |
| leva   | agabalyan | 19560901       |  2012-02-19T11:38:47.972Z |
| leva   | agabalyan | 19560901       |  2011-08-22T11:49:57.995Z |
.....
```

All of these rows have the same name, surname and birth date string fields. The only difference is the creation date. In the real application there are significantly more fields/columns ( about 30 of them) but as you'll see they do not participate in the query. Also I've got significantly more rows like these outside the time range of my search query. So I suppose those shouldn't make a difference as well.

I also have a single rows like this one:

```
| -name-  | -surname-  | -bdate string- |  -creation date-          |
| lyova   | aghabalyan | 19560901       |  2013-06-27T11:19:33.345Z |
```

As you see the difference from the first table is in the name and surname fields. The name differs by 2 symbols and the surname by 1.

For searching I use this query:

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "must":[{
                "fuzzy":{
                    "registration.name":{
                        "value":"lyova",
                        "min_similarity":"0.45"
                    }}
                },
                {"fuzzy":{
                    "registration.surname":{
                        "value":"aghabalyan",
                        "min_similarity":"0.65"
                    }}
                },
                {"term":{
                    "registration.birthDateStr":"19560601"
                }},
                {"range":{
                    "registration.created":{
                        "from":"2011-01-01",
                        "to":"2014-01-01"
                    }
                }}
            ],
            "must_not":[],
            "should":[]}
    },
    "from":0,
    "size":50,
    "sort":[],
    "facets":{}
}
```

This search query returns the 1 row containing `lyova` and 14 rows with `leva`. I don't understand why it is not returning the remaining 26 rows containing `leva` in them. The total number of hits is also 15 while it should have obviously been 41. It seems to me that I've encountered an elasticsearch bug here.

Comment: For debugging purposes see what happens to the results when you remove    each of the last two search criteria. Perhaps it is to do with these?

Comment: I've tried to query for `leva agabalyan` with the same last 2 criteria - all the 40 records are being returned. So my guess is that those 2 are OK and the reason the other 24 rows aren't being returned lies somewhere in the implementation of the fuzzy query :(

Comment: Do you mean all 41 records are returned?

Comment: No. If i search for `lyova(sim:0.3) aghabalyan(sim:0.6) 19560601 dateRange` I'm getting 15 results(1 lyova and 14 leva) but If i search for `leva(sim:0.3) agabalyan(sim:0.6) 19560601 dateRange` I'm getting 40 record(40 leva and 0 lyova). I suppose I should be getting the `lyova` record when searching for `leva`. So this is another strange behavior example.